# Quick action record edit form behaves differently based on page layout

Tags: lightning, form, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

I have a lightning record edit form launched through a quick action that uses the page's recordId to grab fields. On this edit form there is a lookup field.

If I don't include this field on the page layout, the record edit form doesn't load the lookup field's value.

If I include this field on the page layout, the record edit form loads the lookup field's value.

I can't find any info on this in Salesforce's documentation. Any idea what's going on or how I can get around this without having this field on the page layout.